# Search feature not working the way I need it in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a search feature and it keeps showing all the records I am trying to figure how to hide all the records and only show the one i am searching.

controller just the function

```
   function search_keyword()
    {
        $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
        $data['row']    =   $this->inbound_model->search($keyword);
        $this->load->view('pages/test',$data);
    }
```

model just the function

```
function search($keyword)
    {
        $this->db->like('RequestNumber',$keyword);

        $query  =   $this->db->get('requestsnew');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

View

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('inbound/search_keyword');?>" method = "post">
<input type="text" name = "keyword" />
<input type="submit" value = "Search" />
</form>

<?php foreach($row as $r){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r->RequestNumber?></td>
           <td><?php echo $r->EmpName?></td>

    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Not working means

Comment: its working just need it to not show alll the records but just the record I am searching

Comment: unclear with what you need

Comment: in the view it is showing all the data.  I need it not to show all the data but just the one that I am typing in the search field. Like record number 20 or any record number

Comment: add output what you getting and what you need in question... The way you speak confusing me..

Comment: for example it is showing 1 John doe 2 Jane doe 3 Mr smith. I just want those names not to show up and when i start typing in the search field 1 for only record one to show 1. john doe

Comment: its giving me the list of names or records right when page is loaded I don't want the list I only want what I search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out just need to change the like to where clause in the model.

```
function search($keyword)
{
    $this->db->where('RequestNumber',$keyword);

    $query  =   $this->db->get('requestsnew');
    return $query->result();
}
```